# Given son-in-laws old imac, it is still registered under his iCloud and need to switch it to mine.

Tags: icloud, imac

How do I switch iCloud accounts on a gifted imac desktop from son-in-laws to mine. It won't update because it says it is registered to another account. Son in law did give me his iCloud signin info. This is the first Mac I have ever owned so a lot out my experience.

Comment: You should really just erase the hard drive before doing anything. Google if you need help, there are many many articles on how.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign out of his iCloud and then in with yours (or create your free iCloud account if you don't have one). This can all be done in System Preferences.

1. Open the  (Apple) menu in the top left corn
2. Open System Preferences
3. Click on iCloud
4. If your son-in-law's account is still signed in, click the "Sign Out" button in the bottom left corner

At this point, the iMac should be signed out of his iCloud account. On this same screen, you can sign in with your iCloud account and turn on/off the various services you would like to use.

Like a commenter mentioned above, another option is to start fresh by erasing the hard drive. If that is the route you'd like to take, this Apple reference can help walk you through it:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: This is fine... until any of the apps or even the OS itself needs updating - then you'll discover you need the old ID details before it will update. The apps & OS don't belong to the machine, they belong to the original purchaser's Apple ID. I'd just go with option 2. Erase & start over.